# Change all ID values by same Class name

Tags: javascript

I am using the "Autofill" extention on Google Chrome which runs javascript codes. I want to change all ID's `ctl01_ctl00_Main_Main_wtWeighted_txtWeight_xxxxx` numeric values from 0 to 100 by same Class name `weightBox Numeric`.

My best guess was the code below but nothing.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('weightBox Numeric').value = "100";
```

Comment: Please don't rollback the changes made. Regards.

Comment: If you look up [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) in the docs, you'll see why that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a live collection. In other words, it's a sort of array. So you have to loop through each value to change them. Also you can use querySelectorAll here:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".weightBox.Numeric");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].id = i + 1;
}
```